# Python time lagging compared to system time

Tags: python, datetime, time, lag

I am using Python 3.8.5 working on an instance in a virtual environment. My scripts write a log using the standard `logging` module, and I am also getting the time using arrow through `arrow.utcnow().format("m")`. I am also having some `sleep(x)` statements in loops running constantly. This is running on Ubuntu 20.04 with the most recent updates installed.

For some reason, the logged and showed time starts lagging compared to the system time on the instance (around 5 min in an hour). This behaviour is only happening on this particular instance and not on a local machine. This is a first time ever I encounter this kind of issue and I am not sure how to troubleshoot. Would appreciate any suggestions on why this is happening and how to resolve.

Comment: Edited - yes, that's the case.

Comment: Could you add a minimum verifiable example and and example of the output compared to what you'd expect as well? Remember that a `sleep` call won't mean that you'll output something exactly x time between each call

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to identify the root cause of the issue, but it simply went away after updating the system with `sudo apt update && upgrade` and rebooting it, then restarting the scripts.